# I want to replace the second occurrence of the number in the string

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I have a string say a url like below

```
"www.regexperl.com/1234/34/firstpage/home.php"
```

Now i need to replace the 34 number that is the second occurrence of a number in the string with 2.

The resultant string should be like

```
"www.regexperl.com/1234/2/firstpage/home.php"
```

The challenge I m facing is when i try to store the value 34 and replace it , It is replacing the 34 in the number 1234 and gives the result like below

```
"www.regexperl.com/122/34/firstpage/home.php"
```

Kindly let me know a proper regex to solve the problem.

Comment: Is this position of numbers constant ? I mean after first slash and second slash ?

Comment: or regex: `^(\D*\d+\D*)\d+` replace with `\12`

Comment: Its not specific to 34 it can be any number. I just said an example here as 34

Comment: Yes user(noob) the positions are constant.. like /number/number/word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\K`.

```
^.*?\d+\b.*?\K\d+
```

Replace by `your string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/lW2kK1/1

Answer (score 0):

Well if the positions are constant then you can find and replace as follows.

**Regex:** `(\.com\/\d+)(\/\d+)`

**Input string:** `www.regexperl.com/1234/34/firstpage/home.php`

**Replacement to do:** Replace with `\1/` followed by number of your choice. For example `\1/2`.

**Output string:** `www.regexperl.com/1234/2/firstpage/home.php`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB2tR7/1)