# no solution for me. how can i replace second occurence of a find in php

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

im searching a paragrahp (string) for a certain word. and i want to replace that word with another word, but i want to replace on the second occurence of my find.
here is what i tried

```
$string = 'hello my name is hello';
$output = str_replace('hello', 'Gary', $string);
// desired output
//hello my name is Gary
```

It is very simple but i cant get it right. Please bare in mind my string is very long and has all types of characters in it

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to replace the second occurrence of the number in the string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36417838)

Comment: i checked that link. still doesnt help me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

With this regex : `/^.*?hello\b.*?\Khello/` :

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `.*?` matches any character (except newline)
- `\b` assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
- `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

Check this demo : https://regex101.com/r/lW2kK1/2

which gives you :

```
$re = "/^.*?hello\\b.*?\\Khello/"; 
$str = "hello my name is hello"; 
$subst = "Gary"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```